# new cacti installation on ubuntu 12.04 64bit not graphing any data

Tags: ubuntu, cacti

Hey guys i just installed cacti on a ubuntu 12.04 server and am having issues with any data showing up on my graphs.

If i snmpwalk the certain OID it works. I have tailing on the cacti.log file and i see it polling the values correctly but nothing ever graphs.

Is there anything i can check with regards to snmp or something in cacti that may be causing this to not work?

I have already checked in my php.ini and have set the timezone, someone was mentioning that may cause issues.

> [CACTI LOG FILE](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/119790/cactilog.rtf)

UPDATE: added cacti log file

Comment: Did you check "System Utilities -> View Cacti Log File"? What does it say? Is the SNMP community and version correct? Is the Cacti host in the ACL of the SNMP-host you want to query? What data do you want to query? Is the graph-template approriate for your type of host?

Comment: from what i know the device is in the ACL, the template is appropriate. When i manually snmpwalk with the same settings it works.
I will post a log file of the cacti log to show whats going on

Comment: Did you check Cacti's logfiles at "System Utilities -> View Cacti Log File"? Raise loglevel if needed.

Comment: yep i did, i just posted the file and its on debug mode.

Comment: How does your crontab poller.php entry look like? Do you run it every 5 minutes?

Comment: entry? That could be my problem... i never manually added anything into my crontab

Comment: You're polling *something*, so you will have a crontab-entry. Just make sure it's set to 5 minutes. If you had to change it, restart crond and rebuild your poller cache.

Comment: from what i can see this is what is in the crontab file
/usr/share/cacti/site$ crontab -l
MAILTO=root
*/5 * * * * www-data php /usr/share/cacti/site/poller.php >/dev/null 2>/var/log/cacti/poller-error.log

Comment: if i have that in my crontab, in my settings panel i have poller interval as 10 seconds and my cron interval as every minute. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logfiles, you changed the "Poller Interval" in Cacti from the default of "Every 5 Minutes" to "Every 10 Seconds".

The Cacti settings say:

> Poller Interval
>
> The polling interval in use. This setting will effect
>   how often rrd's are checked and updated. NOTE: If you change this
>   value, you must re-populate the poller cache. Failure to do so, may
>   result in lost data.

This won't work unless you also change it in the system's cronjob!

Also we have the cron-interval, just below of it in the settings:

> Cron Interval
>
> The cron interval in use. You need to set this setting
>   to the interval that your cron or scheduled task is currently running.

So, the question is: Do you really need 10-seconds sampling? REALLY? If not, revert everything to "Every 5 Minutes" and then go to "System Utilities -> Rebuild Poller Cache".

Restart cron, in case you made it not be be 5 minutes, and wait for 15 minutes. Graphs should be appearing then.

**EDIT**: Just saw your reply. Do not change crontab, it's ok.

```
Go to: "Settings -> Poller":
Set: Poller Interval = Every 5 Minutes
Set: Cron Interval = Every 5 Minutes
Save
Go to: "System Utilities":
Run "Rebuild Poller Cache"
```

Do not fiddle around with intervals if you don't need to.

Comment: ok sounds good, i have changed them back to 5min and i will let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if i wanted to change it to 1min interval, i modified the crontab to 1 and i changed my polling setting and my cron settings to 1. I restarted cron, and i rebuild poller cache. What could be causing the issue now?

Comment: Change evervything to 5. If that works, you can try another setting. You need to adaot data tempate for it.

Comment: ok i have everything at 5 min and it is working. I guess i dont need it at 1 minute, but if i wanted to what would be the steps now?